# ¿Como Puedo Descargar Y integrar La Api Rest?

Tags: android

Como ya lo he mencionado quiero saber como usar la api Rest en mi app. Gracias.

Comment: Uy pero faltan muchos detalles para saber cómo ayudarte. Por favor, [edit] la pregunta con datos de qué has hecho, código relevante, qué errores tienes y preguntas concretas. Dale un vistazo también a [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las peticiones a *API Rest* funcionan de igual manera que las peticiones que haces a un servidor, solo que la dirección web y el método de consulta varían.

Existen varias librerías Android para facilitar la construcción dichas peticiones, yo recomiendo el uso de [retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/), hay mucha documentación incluso en español.

Comment: Muchas gracias.